# show previews command on terminal?

Tags: history

Like in Windows, where if you press "up_arrow" you can see the last used command and the history of commands used before that (in the current season)

Is there anything like that in ubuntu? I found out about `~/.bash_history` (`cat ~/.bash_history`) but is there no other option?

Comment: Um. Yeah. Use the up arrow to see the last command. If you press it multiple times, you can see previous commands. Also, `history` will show all previous commands that you ran.

Comment: weird, doesn't work for me. I will look on it, Thanks

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: Do you have a `.bashrc` file? Does it say anything about history? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Well, actually Windows "borrowed" that feature from Linux, so... you guess :) If it doesn't work for you, maybe you are using `sh` and not `bash` as your shell?

Comment: yeah check `echo $0`to see your current shell (and `echo $SHELL` to see what your login shell is set to)

Comment: You can check that post to enable bash history https://superuser.com/questions/174306/how-can-i-enable-the-bash-command-history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So confused...

I upgraded to the newest Ubuntu version and it seems to be fixed. The version I used before was probably an older one.

Pretty awesome it's a Linux feature Windows copied! Thanks for the cool information :)

Answer (score 1):

An even better option is to edit your ~/.inputrc. Add these lines:

```
## arrow up
"\e[A":history-search-backward
## arrow down
"\e[B":history-search-forward
```

You can then search previous input lines, so that e.g. typing `su` and then Up/DownArrow will cycle through previous input lines starting with `su`. A lot of typing saved. Good luck :)